# Wine(HQ) gfx problems when running games, how to fix'em?

Tags: wine, games

**specs**:
Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)
kernel 4.15.0-62-generic
Wine amd64 i386 wine4.15-bionic
It uses directx9 d3dx9_42.dll
card GeForce GT 710

**test case: black screen on Skyrim**
I can run Skyrim, I can hear the menu sounds (hit Enter and hit ESC),
so I open the console with ~ and type "load lastSavegameName",
the game loads properly, I can unsheath the weapon and swing it,
musics play, all sounds are ok, I can even spawn a wolf but...
The whole time all the screen is COMPLETELY black! and I can see absolutely nothing on the game window!

Another test: Path of Exile was simply crashing.

**guesses and more tests**

- It seems related to graphics drivers vs something?, I read it could be related to shaders too.
- I tested nvidia drivers 430 and 390 versions, both failed.
- **Noveau** driver **works** (I can see the game logo and menus) but is uber slow and wont let me select other screen resolution than 640x480, unusable even for tests unfortunately.
- I tried to use winetricks to disable GLSL but didnt work either (the idea was to disable shaders)

---

**what worked**
It ran perfecly on ubuntu 16.04,
kernel 4.15.0-50-generic,
wine4.0.0stable-xenial (could may be older ones too like wine2.0.3stable-xenial) (some of these even run on ubuntu 18.04 but the problem persists),
driver nvidia-384_384.130-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (I got the filename from apt cache)

I lost access to my old ubuntu 16.04 (I lost the boot partition), still trying to recreate it, but I want to stay on 18.04.

I will add more info as soon I figure it out or ppl give me tips.

---

PS.: *Is this the correct/best site to ask about a windows app run thru wine on linux, specific issues?*

Comment: I am not quite sure what I did that worked...:  
nvidia driver 435;  
dxvk version 0.20 (not master) with winetricks;  
set prefs ini to full screen and remove W/H cfgs; followed this +- https://linuxconfig.org/improve-your-wine-gaming-on-linux-with-dxvk; sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev vulkan-utils; sudo apt install libvulkan1:i386 libvulkan-dev:i386 vulkan-utils:i386; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa; updated everything and reboot;

Answer (score 1):

updated nvidia driver to latest 435;
winetricks, installed latest dxvk version 0.20 (not master);
set prefs ini to full screen (dxvk complained against windowed mode) and removed W/H cfgs from such file as I couldnt guess the correct one, later I used xrandr and chose the maximum one (not whole screen tho, but it may work too);

followed this: http://linuxconfig.org/improve-your-wine-gaming-on-linux-with-dxvk;

```
sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev vulkan-utils;  
sudo apt install libvulkan1:i386 libvulkan-dev:i386 vulkan-utils:i386;  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa;
```

(use `export WINEDEBUG="err+all"` and install everything required in the ":i386" way in case of complaining about something like wrong class 64 bits)

updated everything thru software-update (including kernel) and reboot;

obs.: this fixed also other games missing custom main menu backgrounds and music or even crashes;

(if it works for someone else, I can mark this as accepted answer)